# Sending special characters in Ajax POST and JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, stringify, encodeuricomponent

@SOLVED

As explained by James M. Lay, I should change my content-type from `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to `application/json`

it implied in an error because it seems that only UrlEnconded types generates POST arrays in server side (at least in PHP). So I had to change the way I receive/deal with the request in my server script

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input'); //yes. php://input

if($json) $params = json_decode($json,true);
else $params = $_POST;
```

I also had to make a few changes in the Javascript code to check the content-type and generate different strings. If it's JSON I just use `JSON.stringify`

```
//string to use in the 'send' method
this.getParametersString = function(){
        if(this.contentType == 'application/json'){
            return JSON.stringify(this.parameters);
        }else{}
}
```

---

I got a question

I`m building a function that receive parameters to write a list of parameters and send it by POST

The problem is that we can't send special characters, such is `+`

So I tried to use the function `encodeURIComponent` to encode them to a URI friendly string.

There comes another problem: if the parameter received is an object, I am loop through the attributes, checking if it is another object or a string, if it is an object, loop again, otherwise encode it.

But it is returning an object of encoded strings. I have to make the object become a string to send it, and for that purpose I use `JSON.stringify`. It decodes the encoded string. So `%2B` becomes `+` again and It is not sent to the server via POST.

on the other hand If I use `stringify` first and the `encodeURIComponent` it generates signs like " and { } that shouldn't be encoded and the string is not a well written JSON

How do you that? Is that a way without using jQuery? Do I have to build my own stringify function?!

Comment: Why not stringify all the params as one and send it? The POST format shouldn't be dependent on the arguments. `stringify` in JS and parse on server.

Comment: Skip the `encodeURIComponent` altogether.  JSON naturally can handle special characters, and JSON.stringify() will automatically take care of most edge cases for you.  The reason you would want to `encode` your POST is if the server is expecting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  Since your server is expecting JSON, you can just send plain ol' JSON up the line.

Comment: @JamesM.Lay maybe this is the point. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is what I have in my `Content-type`. do I need to change it!? I'll try

Comment: The semantically correct content-type header here is `application/json`, but you can also use `text/plain`.

Comment: @JamesM.Lay there seems to be a new problem. I changed my code and now It uses application/json as default content type. I can see special chars (just tested + plus sign) being sent in the headers, but it seems the server isn't being reached. I receive a blank response. but if I change back to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, it works fine (i receive a JSON string). got any idea of what is happening?

Comment: Best thing to do in this situation is check the javascript console.  Press F12 in most browsers, (command-i on Mac I think).  It could be a CORS request error.

Comment: yes I know that. blank response with application/json and JSON string (as expected) with application/x-www-form-urlencoded. the same happens if I use anything that isn't a valid content-Type. so it seems that application/json isn't working for some reason in my server (most likely) or browser

Comment: [below link may help you ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548395/jquery-ajax-post-request-with-special-characters) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548395/jquery-ajax-post-request-with-special-characters

Answer (score 9):

im using the following and i have no issues

```
encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(object_to_be_serialised))
```

Comment: when I have an object like `{number:1}` and I stringify it, it will generate a string as following {"number":1}. if escape this string it generates another string with quotes and curly brackets changed. but they shouldnt have been changed